# Why does node.js app is now working on iPhone?

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

Yesterday i deployed a new NodeJS + React to heroku.
The project works as well on laptops and android but on iPhone (IOS) the screen is froze after the user loggin in.
cannot scroll cannot see images and cannoot click on buttons.
any ideas what can I do?

The main CSS:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  border: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen",
    "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue",
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: var(--color-light);
  color: var(--color-dark);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding the following on the main CSS

```
overflow: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```